Simulate a Web Site's auto form fill
It can be hard to understand because of my english, but here's my question:
The website is using the responses from GET or POST requests to fill in
form elements. I want to automate it in HTML Agility Pack. How do I convert the scripts the website uses to fill in inputs? A method or something else?
I've tried to fill every input manually but it's hard.
string respTrafik = _driver.GetData(adress, "", "").Result;
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument dc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
dc.LoadHtml(respTrafik);

_driver is one of my modified classes and the GetData method uses the httpwebrequest class. After this process, I need to fill a form in dc. Then I will post that form to a url.
In normal browsers, scripts automatically fill all the inputs. I need to find a way to get that algorithm and use it with HAP.

Are you trying to describe JavaScript functionality on the target website?  If you're trying to get the website to invoke that functionality then Html Agility Pack alone may be the wrong tool for the job.  You may instead want to use a "headless browser" like Selenium to scrape the target website, which acts as a full browser engine and executes the JavaScript on the target page.

I was looking into headless browsers like Selenium and Playright. But these libraries create browsers. I guess there is no solution other than doing all the javascript operations manually. Or using a headless browser.

To simulate the auto form-fill functionality of a website in your application using HTML Agility Pack (HAP), you must handle the dynamic behavior that websites typically execute through JavaScript. Since HAP doesn't execute JavaScript, you will need to reverse-engineer how the form is populated and reproduce that logic in your code.
This involves:

Analyzing the Website's Behavior
Manipulating the HTML
Simulating Script Logic
Posting the Data


Right. There seems to be no other way.
